# How can I check whether a city Network Node has already been linked to an Alien Artifact?

Tags: alpha-centauri

One of the rules in Alpha Centauri is that each Network Node in a colony can only be `used` once with an Alien Artifact, to receive the research breakthrough. Other than keeping track manually of each time I use an Artifact at each city, is there any way in the game itself to see whether a city's Network Node hasn't used an artifact yet, so that I don't waste moving an artifact to an already-used city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

Select the Alient Artifact and issue a `G` command ("Go"). The game will show the list of cities, indicating those having **available** Network Nodes.

You need not actually "go" there immediately (e.g., if you need to travel through a non-friendly territory). As soon as you know the city, you may arrange some guard/convoy and move the units manually.

*Caveat*: The list will only show the cities on the current continent, e.g. there must be a land route to destination. Traveling to another continent requires moving there first (e.g., by a Transport).

Comment: Aha - Thank you. I've been using too many mouse commands, it seems :)